# Reacting to A Model Attribute Field Change in Spring Webflow

Tags: spring, spring-webflow, spring-webflow-2

I have a somewhat complex webflow set up to allow forward and backward navigation within the flow. This webflow has a backing object that we'll call flowModel.

So, view states look something like this:

```
<view-state id="beginPage" model="flowModel" view="begin">
    // contents
</view-state>

<view-state id="multipleChoicePage1" model="flowModel" view="choicePage1">
    // contents
</view-state>

<view-state id="multipleChoicePage2" model="flowModel" view="choicePage2">
    // contents
</view-state>

<view-state id="summaryPage" model="flowModel" view="summaryPage">
    // contents
</view-state>
```

The problem occurs when I choose something from one of the choice pages, view it on the summary, then go back in the flow and make a different choice. The summary page will still show values that were computed from the original path.

Is there a way, in webflow, to determine if a field value in the model has changed? If this is the case, I can then manually change the "computed" values, in an `<on-exit>` or `<action-state>`. Otherwise, my only idea is to attach a PropertyChangeListener in the `<on-start>` or `<on-render>` phases inside the `<view-state>`.

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

**Update**

I figured out that by the time an `<on-exit>` method was hit, the new values were already bound to the model. So, I ended up doing this:

```
<view-state id="beginPage">
<on-render>
    <evaluate expression="flowController.enterBeginPage(flowRequestContext)" />
</on-render>
<!-- Transitions -->
<on-exit>
    <evaluate expression="flowController.exitBeginPage(flowRequestContext)" />
</on-exit>
```

Inside the flow controller, the on render and on exit methods looked like this:

```
public void onRenderBeginPage(RequestContext requestContext) {
    MyForm form = requestContext.getFlowScope().get("flowModel",MyForm.class);
    requestContext.getFlowScope().put("originalFlowModel", form);
}

public void onExitBeginPage(RequestContext requestContext) {
        MyForm form = requestContext.getFlowScope().get("flowModel",MyForm.class);
    MyForm originalForm = requestContext.getFlowScope().get("originalFlowModel", MyForm.class);
    requestContext.getFlowScope().remove("originalFlowModel");
    if (!form.getOption().equals(originalForm.getOption()) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

It seemed to work well enough, even though it was a bit of a kludge.

Answer (score 1):

hmmm, I guess you could use multiple flowModel objects maybe?
I don't really like it, but maybe it could work

```
<var name="flowModel" type="FlowModel"/>
<var name="flowModelChoice1" type="FlowModel"/>
<var name="flowModelChoice2" type="FlowModel"/>
<var name="flowModelChoice3" type="FlowModel"/>

<view-state id="beginPage" model="flowModel" view="begin">
    // contents
</view-state>

<view-state id="multipleChoicePage1" model="flowModel1" view="choicePage1">
    <on-entry>
        // copy flowModel into flowModel1
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="event" to="summaryPage">
        // copy flowModel1 into flowModel3
    </transition>
</view-state>

<view-state id="multipleChoicePage2" model="flowModel2" view="choicePage2">
    <on-entry>
        // copy flowModel into flowModel2
    </on-entry>
    <transition on="event" to="summaryPage">
        // copy flowModel2 into flowModel3
    </transition>
</view-state>

<view-state id="summaryPage" model="flowModel3" view="summaryPage">
    // contents
</view-state>
```

Comment: The above was a simplified version of the real thing.
I attempted to put a PropertyChangeListener on the model object, but that listener disappeared as soon as I hit a view state (it made it through some action- and decision-state definitions fine). I ended up having to implement an on-enter method to put a copy of the model in the flow scope, and an on-exit to check against that model.

Comment: I see. so kind of a similar idea except you are doing it outside in your flow controller instead of the xml

Comment: Yes. When drawn out in a state diagram, the flow was too complex to model in the XML, so for the most part each action-state has a method in a  flow controller.